# How to properly produce a label when a button is clicked

Tags: java, javafx

In the code below I have a project that creates 3 buttons called sinister, medium, and dexter. The buttons are properly displayed but are not functional. How do I get the button called sinister in the program to display a label saying “left” when clicked?

```java
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

public class latinTranslator extends Application
{
    private Label myLabel;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button leftButton = new Button("Sinister");
        Button centerButton = new Button("Medium");
        Button rightButton = new Button("Dexter");

        //align centerbutton
        centerButton.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        //event handler
        leftButton.setOnAction(new ButttonClickHandler());
        centerButton.setOnAction(new ButttonClickHandler());
        rightButton.setOnAction(new ButttonClickHandler());

        //label, button and its spacing;
        VBox Vbox = new VBox(20,leftButton, centerButton,rightButton );

        //create scene
        Scene scenebox = new Scene(Vbox,300,500);
        //alignment
        Vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        primaryStage.setScene(scenebox);
        //set scene to stage
        primaryStage.setTitle("Latin Translator");

        //window
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    class ButttonClickHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) 
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the problem _exactly_? _buttons are properly displayed but are not functional_ what do you expect from an empty handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to add `myLabel` to the [scene graph](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/scene-graph-tutorial/scenegraph.htm). Then, in the [event handler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/handlers.htm), you can set the text of `myLabel`.

In the below code, I have indicated changes I made in method `start` with comments. Look for the following comments:

- ADDED THIS LINE
- CHANGE HERE

I have also added the code for method `handle` in class `ButttonClickHandler`

```java
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

public class LatinTranslator extends Application {
    private Label myLabel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        myLabel = new Label(); // ADDED THIS LINE

        Button leftButton = new Button("Sinister");
        Button centerButton = new Button("Medium");
        Button rightButton = new Button("Dexter");

        // align centerbutton
        centerButton.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // event handler
        leftButton.setOnAction(new ButttonClickHandler());
        centerButton.setOnAction(new ButttonClickHandler());
        rightButton.setOnAction(new ButttonClickHandler());

        // label, button and its spacing;
        VBox Vbox = new VBox(20, myLabel, leftButton, centerButton, rightButton); // CHANGE HERE

        // create scene
        Scene scenebox = new Scene(Vbox, 300, 500);
        // alignment
        Vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        primaryStage.setScene(scenebox);
        // set scene to stage
        primaryStage.setTitle("Latin Translator");

        // window
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    class ButttonClickHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            Object source = event.getSource();
            if (source instanceof Button) {
                Button button = (Button) source;
                String text = button.getText();
                if ("Sinister".equals(text)) {
                    myLabel.setText("left");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Run the code and click on button *Sinister* and the word **left** will appear above the button.

This is how it looks before clicking button *Sinister*

[image: before clicking button 'Sinister']

And this is how it looks after clicking button *Sinister*

[image: after]